# How am I supposed to put the title on top of the buttons in the center in the GUI I created using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a newbie and trying to copy the calculator software on my laptop as a project to practice. I'm having such a problem as you see down there:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Root
root = Tk()

#Frame
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()

#Title
ttk.Label(frm, text="Calculator") #How am I supposed to locate this on top of the buttons in the center?

#Buttons
ttk.Button(frm, text="%").grid(column=0, row=0)
ttk.Button(frm, text="CE").grid(column=1, row=0)
ttk.Button(frm, text="C").grid(column=2, row=0)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Del").grid(column=3, row=0)

ttk.Button(frm, text="1/x").grid(column=0, row=1)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Sq").grid(column=1, row=1)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Sqrt").grid(column=2, row=1)
ttk.Button(frm, text="÷").grid(column=3, row=1)

ttk.Button(frm, text="7").grid(column=0, row=2)
ttk.Button(frm, text="8").grid(column=1, row=2)
ttk.Button(frm, text="9").grid(column=2, row=2)
ttk.Button(frm, text="x").grid(column=3, row=2)

ttk.Button(frm, text="4").grid(column=0, row=3)
ttk.Button(frm, text="5").grid(column=1, row=3)
ttk.Button(frm, text="6").grid(column=2, row=3)
ttk.Button(frm, text="-").grid(column=3, row=3)

ttk.Button(frm, text="1").grid(column=0, row=4)
ttk.Button(frm, text="2").grid(column=1, row=4)
ttk.Button(frm, text="3").grid(column=2, row=4)
ttk.Button(frm, text="+").grid(column=3, row=4)

ttk.Button(frm, text="+/-").grid(column=0, row=5)
ttk.Button(frm, text="0").grid(column=1, row=5)
ttk.Button(frm, text=".").grid(column=2, row=5)
ttk.Button(frm, text="=").grid(column=3, row=5)

#Main Loop
root.mainloop()
```

First off I tried to achieve it by using the method grid() but because it works with the columns and rows system, I had problem putting the title in the center.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to put that Label in the root window directly, so it's not affected by the button grid at all.  If it must be in the same Frame as the buttons, `.grid(column=0, columnspan=4)` would be a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `columnspan` keyword argument here so that the label is 4 grid cells wide:

```
ttk.Label(frm, text="Calculator").grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4)
```

Then, increase the `row` values of all the buttons by 1. The result looks like this:

[image: A screenshot of the result]

The [Tk documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.13/TkCmd/grid.html#M11) has additional options for the `grid` command, should you need them.

Answer (score 0):

That's what `columnspan` is for

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Root
root = Tk()

#Frame
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()

#Title
title = ttk.Label(frm, text="Calculator") 
# tell the title to span all 4 columns
title.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4)
#Buttons
ttk.Button(frm, text="%").grid(column=0, row=1)
ttk.Button(frm, text="CE").grid(column=1, row=1)
ttk.Button(frm, text="C").grid(column=2, row=1)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Del").grid(column=3, row=1)

ttk.Button(frm, text="1/x").grid(column=0, row=2)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Sq").grid(column=1, row=2)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Sqrt").grid(column=2, row=2)
ttk.Button(frm, text="÷").grid(column=3, row=2)

ttk.Button(frm, text="7").grid(column=0, row=3)
ttk.Button(frm, text="8").grid(column=1, row=3)
ttk.Button(frm, text="9").grid(column=2, row=3)
ttk.Button(frm, text="x").grid(column=3, row=3)

ttk.Button(frm, text="4").grid(column=0, row=4)
ttk.Button(frm, text="5").grid(column=1, row=4)
ttk.Button(frm, text="6").grid(column=2, row=4)
ttk.Button(frm, text="-").grid(column=3, row=4)

ttk.Button(frm, text="1").grid(column=0, row=5)
ttk.Button(frm, text="2").grid(column=1, row=5)
ttk.Button(frm, text="3").grid(column=2, row=5)
ttk.Button(frm, text="+").grid(column=3, row=5)

ttk.Button(frm, text="+/-").grid(column=0, row=6)
ttk.Button(frm, text="0").grid(column=1, row=6)
ttk.Button(frm, text=".").grid(column=2, row=6)
ttk.Button(frm, text="=").grid(column=3, row=6)

#Main Loop
root.mainloop()
```

Note that you'll also have to move everything else "down" one row to account for the title

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the title label as a child of `root` before the frame:

```py
...
#Title
ttk.Label(root, text="Calculator").grid()

#Frame
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()
...
```